# Insert object in RLMArray property on already persisted object?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have a fairly simple and straightforward issue I'm trying to solve with Realm. I have objects which have an array property on them (threads). When I fetch all the threads via our API, they're all persisted into Realm since the parent objects are individually saved and thus all child objects (messages & users) within the array property are properly persisted as well. But during the lifecycle of the app I need to add new messages into that array property. Here's what I'm attempting to do:

```
func addPubNubMessageToThread(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let info = notification.userInfo as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {

        var embeddedMessage = Message(json: (info["data"] as? NSDictionary)!)

        let threadId = (info["thread"]! as String)

        // Persist the message to Realm for future use
        var respectiveThread = Thread(forPrimaryKey: threadId)
        let realm = RLMRealm.defaultRealm()
        realm.beginWriteTransaction()
        respectiveThread.conversation.insertObject(embeddedMessage, atIndex: UInt(0)) // Always fails here in XCode with the error below
        realm.addOrUpdateObject(respectiveThread)
        realm.commitWriteTransaction()
    }
}
```

But each time I get the following error:

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Setting unique property '_id' with existing value '540729b543dd5d1868a42b5d''
```

For more context, here are my Realm models:

```
class Message: RLMObject {
    dynamic var _id = ""
    dynamic var type = ""
    dynamic var text = ""
    dynamic var author = User()
    dynamic var created = NSDate()
    dynamic var lastUpdated = NSDate()
}

class Thread: RLMObject {
    dynamic var _id = ""
    dynamic var name = ""
    dynamic var conversation = RLMArray(objectClassName: Message.className())
    dynamic var participants = RLMArray(objectClassName: User.className())
    dynamic var created = NSDate()
    dynamic var lastUpdated = NSDate()
}

class User: RLMObject {
    dynamic var _id = ""
    dynamic var name = ""
    dynamic var firstName = ""
    dynamic var lastName = ""
    dynamic var email = ""
    dynamic var phone = ""
    dynamic var username = ""
    dynamic var avatar = NSData()
    dynamic var created = NSDate()
    dynamic var lastUpdated = NSDate()
}
```

Each message has a property called author, and the `_id` it's complaining about is the `_id` of the author (or user object) of the message. The error message is hard to decipher. I think it's saying that I'm trying to create a new user object with a primary key that already exists. If that's the issue, what should I do instead to add new Realm objects to an array property on an already persisted object?

**Edit**

I am setting the primary key for each model like so:

```
override class func primaryKey() -> String {
    return "_id"
}
```

And `_id` is a GUID generated by MongoDB...so it's globally unique.

Comment: Yes, that is what that message means. It doesn't seem like you are actually making _id your primary key, though (this is done by overriding the class method primaryKey). Also please note that primary keys have to be unique among all objects of a certain subclass, not just objects within an array.

Comment: Sorry, by "user object" you were referring to objects of the class User? In that case I don't think that's the exact issue, it looks more like it would be the respectiveThread instance.

Comment: See my edits about delineating the primary key, the uniqueness of `_id` and the line where XCode throws the error (which is actually not the line where I `addOrUpdateObject` but rather where I attempt to insert the new message into the array property)

Comment: And where does message come from? I mean are you sure it hasn't been added before, perhaps implicitly?

Comment: It comes from a notification posted by NSNotificationCenter and there's no other place it would be persisted...it comes in as a JSON websocket payload and then I try to add them to the thread

Comment: Can you share more details on your `forPrimaryKey:` and `json:` class methods?

Comment: forPrimaryKey: is built into Realm, I didn't add that. I'll add the json: class mehtod

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is probably in your the `Message(json:)` initializer. When you process the JSON for the message, I'm guessing the author ID is passed (and perhaps the rest of the author data).  In your initializer you are probably instantiating a new User, rather than getting an instance of the existing User in the Realm.  I recreated your model objects, and then created an existing user, thread and message.  I was able to deserialize a message from JSON and add the new message to the existing conversation array, as long as my deserialization logic grabbed an existing user if it was provided.  Here is my example initializer:

```
init(json : NSDictionary) {
    self._id = json["_id"] as String
    self.type = json["type"] as? String ?? ""
    self.text = json["text"] as? String ?? ""
    self.created = json["created"] as? NSDate ?? NSDate()
    self.lastUpdated = json["lastUpdated"] as? NSDate ?? NSDate()

    if let author = json["author"] as? NSDictionary {
        if let authorId = author["_id"] as? String {
            self.author = User(forPrimaryKey: authorId)
        }
    }

    super.init()
}
```

In this case, my example JSON:

```
{
    "_id": "2",
    "text": "new message", 
    "author": {"_id": "1"}
}
```

And finally, the code that reads the JSON and adds to an already saved thread:

```
var error: NSError?
var jsonDictionary : NSDictionary!
if let dictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.allZeros, error: &error) as? NSDictionary {
    jsonDictionary = dictionary
} else {
    NSLog("\(error)")
    return
}

let realm = RLMRealm.defaultRealm()

realm.beginWriteTransaction()

let newMessage = Message(json: jsonDictionary)
self.thread.conversation.addObject(newMessage)
realm.addOrUpdateObject(self.thread)

realm.commitWriteTransaction()
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when calling
`insertObject`
your object and all child objects are created in the Realm instead of updated if they already exist. If you first explicitly update your object (which applies to all child objects as well), then this should avoid the issue:

```
var persistedMessage = realm.addOrUpdateObject(embeddedMessage)
respectiveThread.conversation.insertObject(persistedMessage, atIndex: UInt(0))
```